# Java MimeMessage email printing header info in body

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, email-headers

A code base I inherited is printing out some header info in the body of email. This is what is being printed:

```
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

If I `message.writeTo(System.out);` right after creating the message, the above text will print out.

Is there a properties file or something somewhere that specifies this stuff?

It also looks like when the mail arrives the outgoing server has written proper/different header information for these three attributes.

Any ideas for removing it?

Also, here is the whole function:

```
private String sendConfirmationEmail (String to, String from, String subject, String body, boolean CCSender) {
  try
  {
    String smtpHost = Properties.smtp;      
    String fromAddress = from;
    String toAddress = to;

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            new InternetAddress(toAddress));

    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC,
            new InternetAddress(fromAddress));

    if (CCSender) {
      message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,
              new InternetAddress(from));
    }
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(body);

    message.saveChanges();

    Transport.send(message);
    return "1:success";
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    return "0:failure "+e.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to create some kind of filter method, or use regex to chunk off the header or something. Maybe provide sample input/output someone could help you.

Comment: *Why* do you want to remove those headers?  They're accurate, as long as the `body` is all-ASCII and has no lines > 998 characters...

Comment: I want to stop them from being printed out in the email. All recipients see these three lines at the top of the email body.

Comment: There is no inherent reason for the headers to end up in the message body.  Quick question: If you change `message.setSubject(subject)` to `message.setSubject(subject.trim())`, does everything work?

Answer (score 2):

These properties are exposed through the java mail api, which are set as header attributes in e.g., [MimeMessage](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html).

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setHeader("MIME-Version", "1.0" );
msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=us-ascii" );
```

The headers can in turn be changed by mail servers according to their local policy. Inter-mail servern communication could well be performed using e.g. `gzip` compression where another set of headers will be required.

**[EDIT]** If you observe the [source code for `MimeMessage`](http://kickjava.com/src/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.java.htm#2011) you will see that some headers are set default, like `setHeader("MIME-Version", "1.0");`.

Comment: Yes, but how do I get them out of the body of my email?

Comment: @estubey, you don't, as headers to the *request/response* they are not part of the body unless manually copied into it.

Comment: Not sure where they would being copied from. When I do this in my function:

Comment: MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.writeTo(System.out);

The content output contains:

Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Comment: The `toString()` routine of the `Message` as it also encapsules the headers. Apparently, the *default* headeres are printed.

Comment: So if it is being copied in it may be deeper in the code stack.

Comment: I don't think your comment about gzip compression is accurate.  `base64` would make more sense.